# I am changing the value of infoLabel2.Text = newValue.ToString(); in back end C# but the display does not change?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML

```
<t:InfoBulletLabel Text="To provide and maintain the Servicexxx" />
```

and this C# class:

```
public partial class InfoBulletLabel : Grid
{
    public InfoBulletLabel()
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(0, 5);
        SetDynamicResource(Label.MarginProperty, "InfoBulletMargin");
        var grid = new Grid();
        this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(14, GridUnitType.Star) });
        this.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });

        var infoLabel1 = new InfoLabel() {
            Text = "•"
        };
        var infoLabel2 = new InfoLabel();
        
        Children.Add(infoLabel1, 0, 0);
        Children.Add(infoLabel2, 1, 0);

    }

    private static void TextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var infoLabel2 = (InfoBulletLabel)bindable;
        infoLabel2.Text = newValue.ToString();
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(InfoBulletLabel), default(string), propertyChanged: TextPropertyChanged);

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

}
```

I see the correct information being put into here:

```
infoLabel2.Text = newValue.ToString();
```

but the display doesn't change.

Anyone have any idea what is wrong?

For reference. Here's the InfoLabel class:

```
public class InfoLabel :Label
{
    public InfoLabel()
    {
        this.SetDynamicResource(Label.FontFamilyProperty, "Default-Regular");
        this.SetDynamicResource(Label.FontSizeProperty,   "InfoTextFontSize");
        this.SetDynamicResource(Label.TextColorProperty,  "InfoLabelColor");
        LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap;
         VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TextPropertyChanged` method, bindable is a object type of `InfoBulletLabel` not type of `InfoLabel`:

If you want to change the text of `infoLabel2`, make it as a public property:

```
public partial class InfoBulletLabel : Grid
{
    public InfoLabel  infoLabel2;

    private static void TextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var MyInfoBulletLabel = (InfoBulletLabel)bindable;
        MyInfoBulletLabel.infoLabel2.Text = newValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

You use the same name and it may cause some misunderstanding. `InfoBulletLabel`  is a `Grid` with custom property `Text` AND `infoLabel2` is type of `Label` which has a `Text` property too.

Comment: I also opened up another question with a different way of doing this. Can you have a look at the more recent question. Thanks

Comment: If my answer helps your in this question, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).  My workmate will support you in another question:).

Answer (score 1):

the labels you added in the grid they need to be global variables.

```
public partial class InfoBulletLabel : Grid
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(InfoBulletLabel), "Default", propertyChanged: TextPropertyChanged);

        public static InfoLabel infoLabel1 = new InfoLabel();
        public static InfoLabel infoLabel2 = new InfoLabel();

        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }

        public InfoBulletLabel()
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 5);
            SetDynamicResource(MarginProperty, "InfoBulletMargin");
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(14, GridUnitType.Star) });
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });

            infoLabel1.Text = "•";
            infoLabel2.Text = Text;

            Children.Add(infoLabel1, 0, 0);
            Children.Add(infoLabel2, 1, 0);

        }

        private static void TextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            infoLabel2.Text = newValue.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I also opened up another question with a different way of doing this. Can you have a look at the more recent question. Thanks